# Command insert requires authentication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have tried this

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/ninjago', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

to connect mongodb on nodejs and working fine.

But when i try to create data, it gives this error

> "(node:18194) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: command insert requires authentication"

can anyone help me out? i am using ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 10):

Specify the username and password in your MongoDB URI.  Something like:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost/ninjago', …
```

Reference:

- [Mongoose Connections Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check if the database name exist and specify the port